# Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart

after formatting my pc , i tried to run my app for debugging but i get the following

[image]

b4 the format everything was fine .

Comment: any update on your issue? I am also on the same boat.

Comment: yes i solved it .. it happened because i updated java to latest version which is not supported the latest gradle file version  . i was using jave 19 with gradle v8.0.2 . so now i use jave 19 with gradle-7.6 . it solved my issue .. and don't forget to edit it on gradle-wrapper.properties file so it look like distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

it happened because I updated java to latest version which is not supported the latest gradle file version . i was using jave 19 with `gradle` v8.0.2 . so now i use `jave 19` with gradle-7.6 . it solved my issue .